# No Apollo Client instance can be found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

```
No Apollo Client instance can be found. Please ensure that you have called `ApolloProvider` higher up in your tree.

function LoginForm(props) {
    const client = useApolloClient();
      function userLogin(code){
          googleAuthenticate(code.code)
           .then(res => {
```

I'm getting this error when trying to access the apollo client.

I have 2 files, InitApollo and WithApollo. One initiates the Apollo client and the other is a HOC to wrap all Next.js pages inside of it.

I have an _app.tsx file which is the root of all the other pages/components, and it contains a provider as shown here.

```
import App from 'next/app';
import React from 'react';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import withApollo from '../lib/withApollo';

class MyApp extends App<any> {
  static displayName = 'MyApp';

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, apolloClient } = this.props;
    console.log(apolloClient);
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withApollo(MyApp);
```

The component that gets the actual error is a "LoginForm" React component that is within a Next.js Page. Both the page and the LoginForm component are wrapped with "withApollo", which I assume should give access to the Apollo client?

**LoginPage.tsx (Next.Js Page)**

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps(context) {
    const { loggedInUser } = await isLoggedIn(context.apolloClient);
    if (loggedInUser) {
      redirect(context, '/dashboard');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LoginLayout>
        <div id="loginform">
          <LoginForm></LoginForm>
        </div>

        <style jsx>{`
          #loginform {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          }

          .row {
            flex: 1;
          }
        `}</style>
      </LoginLayout>
    );
  }
}

export default withApollo(LoginPage);
```

And this is the **LoginForm.tsx** which contains the login logic.

```
function LoginForm(props) {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  function userLogin(code) {
    googleAuthenticate(code.code)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        document.cookie = cookie.serialize('token', res, {
          maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
        });

        client.writeData({
          data: {
            isLoggedIn: true,
          },
        });

        client.cache.reset().then(() => {
          redirect({}, '/dashboard');
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="xxx"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={userLogin}
        onFailure={userLogin}
        cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
        hostedDomain={'xxx'}
        responseType={'code'}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withApollo(LoginForm);
```